# Android spinner doing ItemSelectedListener in the OnCreate

Tags: java, android

In my code, when you select an item in the Spinner, the application changes screen. However, when it is loading for the first time, it performs the ItemSelectedListener. I need it to perform the code only when I select an item in the Spinner, not when the form loads.

The code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_location_layout);

Spinner spnEUID = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnEUID);
final DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

ArrayList<String> EUIDs = handler.GetAllAOI();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, EUIDs);
spnEUID.setAdapter(adapter);

final EditText txtEUID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtScanEUID);
txtEUID.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            PublicVariables.AOI = handler.getAOI(Integer.parseInt(txtEUID.getText().toString()));
            Intent intent = new Intent(SelectLocationScreen.this, RaploScanScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    }
});

spnEUID.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener () {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        PublicVariables.AOI = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(SelectLocationScreen.this, RaploScanScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding a variable like `previousSelection` in my OnItemSelectedListener:

- If it is `null`, it's a false alarm.
- If it's not, the user made this choice.

---

Here's my answer to a similar question, I wrote this one to avoid your problem and when the user selects the same item again. [Odd Android Spinner behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14113164/1267661)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried something similar to this. My error was where I declared the variable. Thanks again!