# Android:Get result Dynamically through Spinner

Tags: android, android-emulator

I,m new to android can anybody help me out this simple one but I can't able to recognize how this execution process.I need to get Result Dynamically through Spinner but here spinner executes while at runtime only(Without click on spinner)
Sorry to ask this question im unable to solve this...:(

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loanpayment);
    try {
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(a);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(item.equals("Yearly")) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9 .]*)");

                if (et1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && et2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && et3.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(et1.getText().toString().trim());
                    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(et2.getText().toString().trim());
                    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(et3.getText().toString().trim());

                    if (m.matches() && m1.matches() && m2.matches()) {

                        amount = Float.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());
                        interest = Float.valueOf(et2.getText().toString());
                        year = Float.valueOf(et3.getText().toString());
                        s1 = interest/100;
                        s2 = year;
                        ans1 = s1 * amount;
                        ans2 = (float) (1-Math.pow((1+s1), -s2));
                        tot = (float) Math.round(ans1/ans2);
                        String an = Float.toString(tot);
                        ans.setText("Amount to Pay=" +an);

                    } 
                     else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Incorrect value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. What results are you getting and what results do you want?

Comment: @codeMagic--      here in the program I want result dynamically through spinner,so i wrote program in spinner onItemSelected. so,here on at runtime it executes spinner not considering other fields

Comment: @codeMagic Could you update your question with your clarified explanation?

Comment: @rhughes ??? My question was pretty clear. I didn't know what the OP was getting or wanting exactly

Comment: @rhughes--Read edited one

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry! I mean to speak to the OP...

Comment: @user2174439 have you tried my solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113164/odd-android-spinner-behavior/14114880#14114880) should solve your problem

As @Sam states in a comment there

> ... Spinners call onItemSelected() when
>   they load the default value.

So, my understanding is that `onItemSelected()` will be called when the `Spinner` is loaded so you need to use some flag to let the function know that it is originally loaded and skip the logic. Then you can change the flag so the function will continue with the logic after an item is selected by the user. Hope this helps.

**Note**

I haven't yet found anything in the docs regarding this but I have stepped through the function to verify that this happens.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you set your spinner.setOnItemClickListener it get called once as soon as layout is layed, you have to handle it manually setting some flag

Comment: Can't we call this dynamically??